# Calling the setter of a super class in a mixin

Tags: python, mixins, super

Suppose I have the following (not quite biologically correct) classes:

```
class AnimalBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._limbs = None

    @property
    def limbs(self):
        return self._limbs

    @limbs.setter
    def limbs(self, value):
        self.paws = value
        self._limbs = value


class BipedalMixIn:
    @property
    def limbs(self):
        return super().limbs

    @limbs.setter
    def limbs(self, value):
        self.bipedal = (value == 2)
        # does not work
        super().limbs = value
```

Here `super().limbs = value` is [not supported by python](http://bugs.python.org/issue14965). If `BipedalMixIn` was not a mixin, I could use the super class's name directly, but is there any simple alternative, to call the super class's setter in a mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, although any simpler answers are appreciated.

```
class AnimalBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._limbs = None

    @property
    def limbs(self):
        return self._limbs

    @limbs.setter
    def limbs(self, value):
        self.paws = value
        self._limbs = value


class BipedalMixIn:
    @property
    def limbs(self):
        return super().limbs

    @limbs.setter
    def limbs(self, value):
        self.bipedal = (value == 2)
        # works!
        super(BipedalMixIn, self.__class__).limbs.__set__(self, value)


class Bird(BipedalMixIn, AnimalBaseClass):
    pass


bird = Bird()
bird.limbs = 2
print(bird.bipedal)    # True
print(bird.paws)        # 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, if you're working under Python 2.x, make sure all of your classes directly or indirectly inherit from `object`.  Otherwise, `@property` does not work at all.

To steal the example code from [this comment](http://bugs.python.org/issue14965#msg179217) in OP's linked bug:

```
super(BipedalMixin, BipedalMixin).limbs.__set__(self, value)
```

Let's break this apart:

```
super(BipedalMixin, BipedalMixin)
```

Normally, we pass an instance as the first argument.  Here, we're instead passing a class, to look up class attributes specifically and disable any descriptor magic.

```
.limbs.__set__(self, value)
```

This invokes the property's `__set__()` method, which calls the setter.  It is normally invoked automatically by the `foo.limbs = bar` syntax.

Comment: Hmm this gives a `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` under python 3.

Comment: @simon: Please post the traceback (it will be very long, so skip any repetition).

Comment: If I have the class order right, here's the traceback: `...` `super(self.__class__, self.__class__).limbs.__set__(self, value)` `super(self.__class__, self.__class__).limbs.__set__(self, value)`
`self.bipedal = (value == 2)` `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

Comment: You *never* want to call `super` with `self.__class__` as the first argument. It's always wrong. If you inherit from the class that uses it, you'll get infinite recursion, because `self.__class__` isn't the class where the code is located any more, and the parent class you're using `super` to access is in fact the same class you're already in!