# How to call super of enclosing class in a mixin in Python?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code, in Django:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        # Do Stuff A

class Mixin(object):
    def save(self):
        # Do Stuff B

class A(Parent, Mixin):
    def save(self):
        super(A, self).save()
        # Do stuff C
```

Now, I want to use the mixin without blatting the behaviour of the save in Parent. So I when I save, I want to do stuff C, B, and A. I've read [Calling the setter of a super class in a mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664632/calling-the-setter-of-a-super-class-in-a-mixin) however I don't get it and having read the super docs it doesn't seem to answer my question.

THe question is, what do I put in the mixin to make sure it does stuff B and doesn't stop Stuff A from happening?

Comment: Are you sure that inheritance order is right - you'd normally put a mixin *after* the parent...

Comment: I'm not sure, no. My understanding is that if I did it the other way round, the mixin's save method would be overridden by Parent. Is that correct?

Comment: No - the MRO is (for non diamond inheritance) - right to left...

Comment: Fixed. Leave the comments in.

Comment: Also a simple test shows that Mixin's save method is now not called.

Comment: Just ignore me - can I put it down to lack of coffee? :p

Comment: Is this different in newer Django versions? The Mixins should be listed *before* the parent in an in heritance setting, e.g. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about calling super in your mixin class?

```
class Parent(object):
    def test(self):
        print("parent")


class MyMixin(object):
    def test(self):
        super(MyMixin, self).test()
        print("mixin")


class MyClass(MyMixin, Parent):
    def test(self):
        super(MyClass, self).test()
        print("self")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.test()
```

This will give you the output as:

```
$ python test.py
parent
mixin
self
```

Comment: What's very annoying with this is that most IDEs will highlight `MyMixin`'s `super(...).test()` call, because there's technically no parent class on `MixMixin` to call `test()` on.

Comment: @jlh I totally get it, such an eyesore not to have that green check mark on the code inspector.

Comment: Could you pls explain what the super() method refers to in a class without parent ?

Answer (score 14):

The best practice for calling the implementation from the superclass is to use `super()`:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def save(self):
        super(Mixin, self).save()
        # Do Stuff B here or before super call, as you wish
```

What is important is that you call `super()` in each class (so that it propagates all the way) but not the topmost (base) class, because its superclass does not have `save()`.

Note that when you call `super(Mixin, self).save()`, you don't really know what the super class would be once it is executed. That will be defined later.

Unlike some other languages, in python, the end class will always have a linear list of classes from which it inherits. That is called MRO ([Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)). From MRO Python decides what to do on `super()` call. You can see what the MRO is for your class this way:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class '__main__.Model'>, <class '__main__.Mixin'>, <type 'object'>)
```

So, `A`'s super is `Parent`, `Parent`'s super is `Model`, `Model`'s super is `Mixin` and `Mixin`'s super is `object`.

That is wrong, so you should change `A`'s parents to:

```
class A(Mixin, Parent):
```

Then you'd have a better MRO:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.Mixin'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class '__main__.Model'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Answer (score 8):

@Click2Death answer is correct, however, when you call `super().test()` inside your mixin class most IDE will claim that `test` is unresolved, which is correct.

[image]

Here is how to make your IDE happy and your code better.

```py
class Parent(object):
    def test(self):
        print("parent")


class MyMixin(object):
    def test(self):
        super_test = getattr(super(), 'test')
        if super_test and callable(super_test):
            super_test()
        print("mixin")


class MyClass(MyMixin, Parent):
    def test(self):
        super().test()
        print("self")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.test()
```

This is Python 3 code, to make it working with Python 2 you need to pass two arguments to the `super(MyClass, self)` call

Answer (score 4):

## Django Example (Python 3+)

To expand on [Vladimir Prudnikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090180/1164465) in a Django context, the template view mixin class could be structured as shown below.

```py
from django.views.generic.base import View


class MyViewMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super_dispatch = getattr(super(), 'dispatch')
        if super_dispatch and callable(super_dispatch):
            return super_dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise RuntimeError('MyViewMixin must be used as part of a '
            'multiple inheritance chain that includes a Django template-view')


class MyCustomView(MyViewMixin, View):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```